# How to replace varying text from a String

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have this HTML portion presented to me in a String.

```
<h1 id="Table1">Hello And welcome</h1>
<h1 id="Table2">Hello And welcome</h1>
<h1 id="Table3">Hello And welcome</h1>
<h1 id="Table4">Hello And welcome</h1>
```

I am trying to remove the `id="*"` attribute from the above string. So that the final String should contain only this:

```
<h1>Hello And welcome</h1>
<h1>Hello And welcome</h1>
<h1>Hello And welcome</h1>
<h1>Hello And welcome</h1>
```

I am using the `replaceAll()` method, but am unable to construct a regex to do so. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String result = subject.replaceAll("<h1 id=\"[^\"]*\">", "<h1>");
```

should work for this simple scenario.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String s = 
                    "<h1 id=\"Table1\">Hello And welcome</h1>"+
                    "<h1 id=\"Table2\">Hello And welcome</h1>"+
                    "<h1 id=\"Table3\">Hello And welcome</h1>"+
                    "<h1 id=\"Table4\">Hello And welcome</h1>";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\sid=\".*?\"", ""));
```

output

```
<h1>Hello And welcome</h1><h1>Hello And welcome</h1><h1>Hello And welcome</h1><h1>Hello And welcome</h1>
```